# BlenderGIS get SRTM Error

Tags: python, error

I am using blender 2.90. I installed the BlenderGIS add-on and tried using it. The Basemap function works fine bht when i try to use Get_STRM, i get the following:

RuntimeError: Error, Unable to open raster.

Please help me ASAP. [image: error]

Comment: See https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/305

Comment: Also please copy the output from the console and paste here as a text block. Mobile phone  images of screens can be difficult to read on some monitors.